# Is ceramic capacitor suitable for snubber?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ceramic, snubber

Is there any Problem to put a ceramic capacitor (0.1nf/2kv) in a snubber circuit.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind also add the circuit of it (I added one from Wikipedia to your question)?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar I approved the edit, but I'm having second thoughts. The circuit has numerous elements which may not be relevant to the question.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar why have you added this circuit - the OP asks for 0.1nF (=100pF) capacitors not 10nF.

Answer (score 2):

Basic snubber circuits are: -

- Resistor in series with a capacitor
- Diode in series with a parallel resistor and capacitor

The "well-known" and documented potential problem with ceramic capacitors is their high Q (very low effective series resistance, ESR). This can cause unnecessary "ringing" and voltage peaks that can exceed voltage ratings for some semiconductor devices.

It can cause problems on power supplies of certain types but, as a snubber, the ESR is  limited by the series resistor or the series diode.